# How to display a dynamic list of buttons one aside another?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am using Recyclerview with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager =
            new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

I want variable columns having fixed height row.

> item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/category_name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Desired View Example

[image: Desired view]

> Current view

[image: Current view]

Comment: post your item xml

Comment: @NaveenDew I have posted it

Answer (score 0):

use this property

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

with buttons button this is not a solution to the large texts.

hope this will help you.

Comment: If I use **android:singleLine="true"** text will truncated. I don't want this. I want to adjust my layout like I have mentioned in the **desired view image**

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour that you want to achieve is not possible using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` (according to my knowledge), because you must specify number of rows or columns that will have the same size.

The effect that you want to achieve could be possible with the [ChipsLayoutManager](https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager) library. I have used it with great success and can highly recommend it.